# How to get Liferay Dynamic Data Lists RecordId (ddlRecordId) in workflow script

Tags: liferay, workflow, dynamic-data-list

I'm trying to integrate Liferay Dynamic Data Lists into Kaleo Workflow (Liferay 6.1 CE GA2), but how to get the ddlRecordId in workflow? I did some homework, I checked all Attributes in serviceContext, but there is no "ddlRecordId" in the serviceContext Attribute, only a key named "recordId" and its value always is 0. Also I can get some field value in the serviceContext Attributes, such as select and textarea. But what I want is the upload file field. Thanks.

```
long ddlRecordId = GetterUtil.getLong(serviceContext.getAttribute("ddlRecordId"));
DDLRecord ddlRecord = DDLRecordLocalServiceUtil.getRecord(ddlRecordId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Liferay 6.1 the **DDLRecordId** is equivalent to the **entryClassPK** in the Workflow Context Variables. This could be a helpful [documentation](http://www.liferay.com/fr/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/lp-6-1-dgen08-designing-workflows-with-kaleo-designer-for-java-0) (read section about Workflow Context Variables)

So, you can get the upload file field by this way :

```
import com.liferay.portlet.documentlibrary.store.DLStoreUtil;
import com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.model.DDLRecord;
import com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.service.DDLRecordLocalServiceUtil;
import com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatamapping.storage.Field;
import com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatamapping.model.DDMStructure;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONFactoryUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.json.JSONObject;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.Serializable

DDLRecord ddlRecord = DDLRecordLocalServiceUtil.getDDLRecord(GetterUtil.getLong(entryClassPK));
// get the upload field
Field field = ddlRecord.getField("field_attachment");
if (field != null){
    DDMStructure structure = field.getDDMStructure();
    Serializable fieldValue = field.getValue();
    String value = String.valueOf(fieldValue);
    if (!value.isEmpty()){
        JSONObject fileJSONObject = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject(value);
        String fileName = fileJSONObject.getString("name");
        String filePath = fileJSONObject.getString("path");
        File file = DLStoreUtil.getFile(structure.getCompanyId(), 0L, filePath);
    }
}
```

I hope this will help more than one...

Answer (score -1):

i had the same problem. I´ve been like a week trying to solve it and finally I get it.
I hope it will solve yours to.

I had to recover all the DDLRecords in a list and find the one is ussing my workflow with the "recordSetId" attribute compared with the "recordSetId" of DDLRecord.

The final code is like this:

```
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants;
import com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext;
import com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatamapping.storage.Field;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.workflow.WorkflowConstants;
import com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.GetterUtil;
import com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.model.DDLRecord;
import com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.model.impl.DDLRecordImpl;
import com.liferay.portlet.dynamicdatalists.service.*;

long companyId = GetterUtil.getLong((String) workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_COMPANY_ID));
String uuid = (String) workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_USER_ID);

ServiceContext serviceContext = (ServiceContext) workflowContext.get(WorkflowConstants.CONTEXT_SERVICE_CONTEXT);

long ddlRecordId = GetterUtil.getLong(serviceContext.getAttribute("recordSetId"));
List ddlRecordList = DDLRecordLocalServiceUtil.getDDLRecords(0,DDLRecordLocalServiceUtil.getDDLRecordsCount());
for(DDLRecord o : ddlRecordList){
    if(o.getRecordSetId()==ddlRecordId){
        Field field = o.getField("status");

        String status = GetterUtil.getString(field.getValue());

        if (status.contains("not")) {
        returnValue = "No"
        }
        else {
        returnValue = "Yes"
        }
    }

}
```